# Rails Postgres - How to add array of hashes in jsonb data type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I have one model in which i have to store array of hashes for 2 fields. i take jsonb data type for that field my field name is reimbursement and other . here how i am adding data into it.

```
TaxSpecial.create!(..other: [
                           {reimbursement_label: "hello1", 
                            reimbursement_fee: 400, 
                            reimbursement_fee_tax: 400
                           },
                           {reimbursement_label: "hello2", 
                            reimbursement_fee: 5000, 
                            reimbursement_fee_tax: 500
                           }])
```

The record look like this

```
#<TaxSpecial id: 9, contract_id: 47, inspection: 9000, inspection_tax: 900, past_reg_fee: 8000, past_reg_fee_tax: 800, settlement_fee: 7000, settlement_fee_tax: 700, tax_return_fee: 900, tax_return_fee_tax: 90, year_end_adj_fee: 5000, year_end_adj_fee_tax: 500, status: "draft", deleted_at: nil, created_user_id: 102, updated_user_id: 102, created_at: "2019-07-26 09:26:48", updated_at: "2019-07-26 09:26:48", other: [{"reimbursement_label"=>"hello1", "reimbursement_fee"=>400, "reimbursement_fee_tax"=>400}, {"reimbursement_label"=>"hello2", "reimbursement_fee"=>5000, "reimbursement_fee_tax"=>500}]>
```

I want to use `link_to_add_fields` for adding and removing other jsob field.

How can i do that in view side to manage dynamic add remove fields of jsonb object?